# How do I select the ID of a parentNode from an Input with DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, input

When I click on the Input it should give me the ID of the div, but instead that give me an error in console "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined".

```js
function add(){
  console.log(this.parentNode.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="add()">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>Price</p>
  <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a parameter at `add` function and pass `this` to the function call. Without using `.onclick` or `.addEventListener()` attached to the element `this` is the global object `window` within the function call at event attribute handler at JavaScript at browser

```js
function add(el) {
  console.log(el.parentNode.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="add(this)">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>Price</p>
  <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, using `.addEventListener()`

```js
function add(event) {
  console.log(this.parentNode.id);
}

onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("#example input[value='click me']")
  .addEventListener("click", add)
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <input type="button" value="click me">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>Price</p>
  <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
function add(target){
  alert(target.parentNode.getAttribute('id'));
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="add(this)">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>Price</p>
  <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

onclick="add(this)"

function add(ele)

Pass and receive the element into the function my friend